# I get a stack overflow error for this code:

Tags: java, recursion

I am a newbie in java and I don't know why this code gives a stack overflow error....

```
int lcm = 0;
public int a (int n1,int n2) {

     n1 = 6;
     n2 = 5;
    if(n1>n2) {
        lcm = n1;
    }
     else if(n2>n1) {
        lcm = n2;
    }
        if(lcm%n1 == 0 && lcm%n2 == 0) {
            lcm = lcm;            
        }
        else {
            ++lcm;
            a(6,5);
    }
    return (lcm);
}
 public static void main (String[] args) {

    ktm ob = new ktm();
    int ans = ob.a(6,5);
    System.out.println(ans);

}
```

I expect to calculate the lcm of two numbers using recursion but it gives me this error message : 
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at ktm.a(ktm.java:25)

Comment: You always modify `n1` and `n2` to `6` and `5` regardless of what you are passed; and what do you think `a(6,5);` does in your `else` block?

Answer (score 1):

You are always sending 6 and 5 as a input to your function, which makes your function in a infinite call for that input because the if condition (lcm%n1 == 0 && lcm%n2 == 0) will not satisfy for the given input.

- If you want to use recursion to calculate LCM than try this

  ```
  int gcd(int a, int b) 
  { 
  if (a == 0) 
      return b;  
  return gcd(b % a, a);  
  } 

  int lcm(int a, int b) 
  { 
      return (a*b)/gcd(a, b); 
  } 
  public static void main (String[] args) {
    ktm ob = new ktm();
    int ans = ob.lcm(6,5);
    System.out.println(ans);
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function solution(a,b){

    function gcd(a,b){
    
        while(b){
          [a,b]=[b,a%b];
          return b;
        }
    }
    function lcm(a,b){
      return a*b/gcd(a,b);
    
    }
return lcm(a,b);

}

var res = solution(20,15);
console.log(res);
```

Here is a function gcd in above javascript snippet in that we have swapped values using destructuring concept of ES6.
Then again a function lcm that returns both numbers multiplication and divide it by calling gcd(a,b)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).